# EC2 1/2 status checks while replacing the volume

Tags: linux, volume, ec2

So, I an EC2 instance and 2 volume with 8GB and 50GB. Initially 8GB was mounted to root device (/dev/sda1). I intended to switch root to 50GB. Here are the steps, I followed:

```
- Stop the instance
- De-attach 8GB
- De-attach 50GB
- Attach 50GB to instance using /dev/sda1
- Start the instance
```

Now, I see status checks 1/2 passed. I can not login to machine. Can anyone explain how to fix this issue? I stopped and started the instance again but it did not work. Please help.

Comment: You probably need to wait for a while before restarting the instance. I do not think it has anything to do with your (re)attaching EBS storage devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop the instance
2. Detach the 8GB
3. Snapshot the 8GB
4. Create a new volume using the snapshot created of desired capacity, .e.g 50GB
5. Attach the new volume using /dev/sda1
6. Boot the instance
7. Grow the file system on /dev/sda1 (exact command depends on the file system, e.g. for xfs it is xfs_growfs), otherwise you will see only 8GB as available capacity, though the disk you created is larger.
8. Optionally move data from the other 50GB to the new disk, and detach it